# Recode/replace variables conditionally with R dyplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use the following code to recode my variables conditionally so that the values in var 2 are replaced by NA if there is any value greater than 0 in var1. If var1 has no value greater than 0 (which is coded as NA), then the value in var2 should remain as it is. The line of code below codes everything in var2 to NA and does not keep the values in var2 if var1 is NA. I have also tried to use na_if() and coalesce() with not much success. Any possible fix to this?

```
df <-  df %>% 
    mutate(var2 = if_else(var1 > 0, NA, var2 = TRUE ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need `var2 = TRUE`, instead it should be `var2`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(var2 = ifelse(var1 > 0, NA, var2))
```

`if_else` is type specific, so you need to have the correct `NA` type matching the 'var2' type.  Assuming it is `numeric` :

```
df %>%
   mutate(var2 = if_else(var1 > 0, NA_real_, var2))
```

---

But, this can be also done with :

```
df %>%
    mutate(var2 = replace(var2, var1 > 0, NA))
```

Or with `case_when` :

```
df %>%
     mutate(var2 = case_when(var1 > 0 ~ NA_real_, TRUE ~ var2))
```

Comment: Thanks, answer accepted! Also, the second ifelse version of the code still does  not work and it will recode all variables in var2 to NA. The replace and case when versions work fine.

Comment: @EvaBalgova One thing I forgot is if the 'var2' class is integer, use `NA_integer_` instead of `NA_real_` as `case_when` is type specific

Comment: @EvaBalgova. Okay, you meant `if_else` instead of `ifelse` (sorry, i missed that `_`).  It is also type specific that is if you use `NA` alone it can be `NA_logical_`, `NA_real`, specify the `NA_real_` and it should work